# Generate month & year array from two dates in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, date

Generate month & year array from two dates in PHP

i have **two** `MM/YYYY` from **form**
ex:

```
$start = "2/2016";
$end = "11/2017"
```

i need the output in all array of months And year
like this in php

```
$monthArray = Array ( 
                 [0] => 2 
                 [1] => 3 
                 [2] => 4 
                 [3] => 5 
                 [4] => 6 
                 [5] => 7 
                 [6] => 8 
                 [7] => 9 
                 [8] => 10 
                 [9] => 11 
                 [10] => 12 
                 [11] => 1 
                 [12] => 2 
                 [13] => 3 
                 [14] => 4 
                 [15] => 5 
                 [16] => 6 
                 [17] => 7 
                 [18] => 8 
                 [19] => 9 
                 [20] => 10 
                 [21] => 11 
            );

$yearArray = Array ( 
                 [0] => 2016 
                 [1] => 2016 
                 [2] => 2016 
                 [3] => 2016 
                 [4] => 2016 
                 [5] => 2016 
                 [6] => 2016 
                 [7] => 2016 
                 [8] => 2016 
                 [9] => 2016 
                 [10] => 2016 
                 [11] => 2017 
                 [12] => 2017 
                 [13] => 2017 
                 [14] => 2017 
                 [15] => 2017 
                 [16] => 2017 
                 [17] => 2017 
                 [18] => 2017 
                 [19] => 2017 
                 [20] => 2017 
                 [21] => 2017 
            );
```

Function would be better. Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: What code have you tried so far? What are the issues? Errors?

Comment: That desired format doesn't look at all easy to work with. Why not just a single array of `DateTime` objects?

Comment: i have  achieved it . But without a function. up-to  3 years only

Comment: I would rather have an array like; `["2016" => array(11,12),"2017" => array(1,2)]` https://3v4l.org/BRcRN OPs array looks like a mess to work with

Answer (score 7):

If you want to use datetime you can do:

```
<?php
$start = date_create_from_format("m/Y","2/2016")->modify("first day of this month");
$end = date_create_from_format("m/Y","11/2017")->modify("first day of this month");

$timespan = date_interval_create_from_date_string("1 month");

$months = [];
$years = [];

while ($start <= $end) {
    $months[] = $start->format("m");
    $years[] = $start->format("Y");
    $start = $start->add($timespan);

}

print_r([ $months, $years ]);
```

Example: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8bfa8cc9481aa8a13d83f62d9c1c6c7927654842

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$start = "2/2016";
$end = "11/2017";

$start = explode('/', $start);
$end = explode('/', $end);

$d1 = strtotime($start[1] . '-' . $start[0] . '-01');
$d2 = strtotime($end[1] . '-' . $end[0] . '-01');
$min_date = min($d1, $d2);
$max_date = max($d1, $d2);

$month = [];
$year = [];
while (($min_date = strtotime("+1 MONTH", $min_date)) <= $max_date) {
    $month[] = date('m',$min_date);
    $year[] = date('Y',$min_date);
}
print_r($month);
print_r($year);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work faster and use less memory than the existing answers because it doesn't rely on creation and manipulation of date objects (especially parsing strings into date objects):

```
/**
 * Takes start and end date string in format 'mm/yyyy' along with a $months and $years
 * arrays; modifies the arrays in place to add all months and years between the dates
 */
function listMonthsAndYears($start, $end, &$months, &$years) {

  list($startM, $startY) = array_map('intval', explode('/',$start));
  list($endM, $endY)     = array_map('intval', explode('/',$end));
  $m = $startM;
  $y = $startY;

  while($endY > $y || ($endY === $y && $endM >= $m) ){
    $months[]= $m;
    $years[] = $y;
    $m++;
    if($m > 12){ // loop to the next year
      $m = 1;
      $y++;
    }
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
$start = '2/2016';
$end = '11/2017';
listMonthsAndYears($start, $end, $months, $years);
```

[**Live demo**](https://ideone.com/NuAE0J)